# Old code still being executed in ipython after files have been modified

Tags: python, import, module, namespaces, ipython

In file1.py:

```
def foo():
    import file2
    print "I'm the old file1.py"
    file2.bar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

In file2.py

```
print "I'm the old file2.py"

def bar():
    print "I'm in the old file2.bar()"
```

On line 5 of the interactive session below, after making modifications to file1.py and file2.py changing all three occurrences of the word `old` to `new`, the `new` code in file2.py is still not used.

```
wim@wim-ubuntu:~/sandpit$ ipython
>>> run file1.py
I'm the old file2.py
I'm the old file1.py
I'm in the old file2.bar()
>>> !rm file2.pyc 
>>> # modify file1, file2
>>> run file1.py
I'm the new file1.py
I'm in the old file2.bar()
```

Where is it getting the old code from file2.py from?

I must misunderstand something, because I thought (from ipython help on `run`):

> The file is executed in a namespace initially consisting only of
>   `__name__ == '__main__'` and `sys.argv` constructed as indicated. It thus
>   sees its environment as if it were being run as a stand-alone program

I've deleted the .pyc file, and can see from the command `whos` that there is no file2 module present in the namespace.  But why is the import not executed again when running file1 a second time?

Comment: The "deep reload" in `IPython.lib.dreload` (or `IPython.deep_reload` in 0.10.x) might help you with this.

Comment: In case someone has something similar: I though I had a similar problem, except I ran the code with regular python (not in interpreter mode). Even deleting `.pyc` files was of no help. As it turned out, it was just Tmux showing me old output when I scrolled up (using the Vi plugin).

Comment: do you just basically run a new `ipython` session each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`run` does not start a new Python process, but rather executes your code in the current one--not in the current namespace, but in the current Python process, the note from the documentation explains. Because of this, `sys.modules` is still around and the old cached module is used. (Are you familiar with the way Python caches imported modules normally?)

To fix this, run in a new Python process each time. `reload` is more than a little problematic and can lead to headaches that I find aren't worth it.

Comment: what does "To fix this, run in a new Python process each time. reload is more than a little problematic and can lead to headaches that I find aren't worth it." mean? does is it mean I need to start a new `ipython` session each time I update my scripts?

Comment: @CharlieParker The relevant issue comes up when you are running a script that does `import foo`, and you have edited `foo.py`. In that case, you will not pick up the edits. In general, it's probably easier to think about things when you just run any scripts fresh each time.

Comment: I want my scripts to run fresh each time without me having to close ipython, do you know how one does that?

Comment: @CharlieParker I don't think it's impossible if you want them to share a Python environment, rather than run the script in a separate process. To run it in a separate process, use `!` for a system call or use the subprocess module.

Answer (score -1):

## I just met this problem and the solution is simple

This is a text-displaying problem,some code cannot show are hidden from us,what you should do is to copy everything to a .txt file and you will see lots of old stuff,delete them and copy the code back to your file.py

old.py

```py
print("Im the new one")
```

But in a new text file,you will see:

newText.txt

```py
print("I am the old one!!!!")

#This is the old codeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

print("Old codesssssssssss")
```

### I know the explaination is weird,but that's the truth that I saw!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).